# How do you distinguish definitions from theorems?

Tags: logic, soft-question, terminology

I read very often and i highlight definitions in orange and theorems in purple, but sometimes I cant really distinguish a definition from a theorem, for example:

Let $A$ be a finite set and $B$ a nonempty set. $|A|≥|B|$ if and only if there exists a function that maps A onto B.

$|A|$ and $|B|$ represent the cardinality of $A$ and $B$ respectively.

I don't understand if this is a theorem (or a rule in general), or a definition, how do you distinguish definitions from theorems since both usually use the sentence "if and only if"?

Comment: If it is stated that way, it is poor form.  Usually we would write something like "We will write $|A| \geq |B|$ if..." (definition) or "Then $|A| \geq |B|$ if ..." (theorem.)

Comment: It's a definition if it introducing a phrase describing something.  Has cardinality been defined yet?  If so has a method of comparing orders been defined?  If not then this is the first time you've seen it and it is a definition.  ... Also theorems must be proven or justified. If $|A|\ge |B|$ means something *other* then there exist a function from $A$ onto $B$ (what does it mean then?) then why rational do we have that $|A|\ge |B|$ if and ony if there is such a function? How do we *know* that?  Unless it's a what $|A|\ge |B|$ *means*.

Comment: Other phrasings that imply a definition are "We say that $X$ is... if..." or "we call $X$ a ... if..." or use of italics: "We will call $X$ a *Banach space* if..."

Comment: @fleablood I think that definitions ought to be clear enough so that you know you are reading a definition without so much context. e.g., when using a text for a reference instead of reading it exhaustively.

Comment: If it's not the definition, then $\le $ would have been defined somewhere previously... right? This is usually not the definition. The definition is usually that $|A|\le |B|$ means there is an injection from $A$ into $B.$ Then "$|A|\le |B|$ iff there is a surjection $B\to A$" is a theorem (and the backward direction requires the axiom of choice, to boot).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen on Wikipedia it says that this is a definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality, at the beginning i though this was a rule

Comment: @JairTaylor that's a critique of the text.  If a text is *badly* written and you want to determine if what the book says is a definition or a theorem... well, I don't know what to do other than read carefully.  But yes, I text *should* say "we say" or words to that effect.  But I interpret this much as spaceisdarkgreen did.

Comment: @cekami7844 Yes, injection is almost exclusively the definition in my experience... I imagine it would get interchanged with the surjection version a lot if we didn't kinda sorta care about the axiom of choice. What do you mean by "I thought this was a rule"? What did you think was a rule?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen the example i gave above, i thought i was a theorem and it was not a definition since it just gave a relationship between 2 cardinalities

Comment: @cekami7844 Okay, and you're clear that the thing you quoted above is **not** the definition, right? (Quoted in your question, not definition 2 on wikipedia which *is* 
 the usual definition.)

Comment: *how do you distinguish definitions from theorems since both usually use the sentence "if and only if"?* Actually, I've rarely seen "if and only if" used for a definition, because the "only if" is implied.  So the use of "if and only if" could be another context clue that you are looking at a theorem, not a definition, unless a particular author doesn't follow that usage.

Answer (score 5):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

It should not usually be ambiguous whether a given statement is a theorem or definition.  If a definition is not explicitly labeled as such, if will usually  be written in a form such as

- "We will write $|A| \geq |B|$ if..."
- "We say that  is... if..."
- "We call  a ... if..."

or, if the definition is a word (rather than a notation) then a definition will be indicated by italicizing the new term:

- "X is a *Banach space* if...
- "A is *positive definite* if ...

Generally speaking, authors use "if" rather than "if and only if" for a definition because the "only if" part is implied.

If it is not indicated as a definition from the above clues, I would assume it is a theorem (or at any rate, a statement that is not a definition.)  Other clues that a sentence is not a definition is if it starts with *then*, *so*, *thus*.

The example you give

> Let  be a finite set and  a nonempty set. $|A| \geq |B|$ if and only if
>   there exists a function that maps A onto B.

is not standard mathematical writing because sentences should not begin with a symbol.  This makes it somewhat harder to tell if it is a definition or not because of the lack of any word connecting it to the previous sentence, but in the absence of any of the aforementioned cues for a definition I would assume it is not.

Other clues:

- Has the word or notation been used before this?  If there is an index, check it.  (Some books also have an index for notation.)  If it has not been used before, it is likely a definition, although it may be a common term that the reader is expected to know from previous study.
- Is the statement justified in any way by the preceding discussion or previous theorems? If so, it is a theorem.

One last possibility is that it is a definition that has been repeated for convenience.  This will be indicated by words like "recall that":

- "Recall that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is..."

A definition is rarely given inside a proof (unless it has been repeated, as above.)

Not all authors obey these rules - especially if the setting is more informal, such as blackboard work or class notes.  In that case if you are unsure you can always ask the instructor.